# Get slider value of tkinter slider and use it in a while loop for openCV (Python, OpenCV, Tkinter)

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, slider

I want make a small and easy chroma key that should remove a specific color from a desktop broadcast. For this I used Python with the opencv libary for editing and the tkinter libary for adjustment sliders.

I ended up with this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageGrab
import tkinter as tk

def show(val):
    print(w.get())

master = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Scale(master, from_=0, to=255, orient='horizontal', label="slider",command=show)
w.pack()


while True:
    # take screenshot and convert it to numpy:
    img = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,510,510)))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    #                 r   g   b
    lower = np.array([0,150,150]) # <- here should be the slider value
    upper = np.array([255,255,255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('orginal', img)
    # cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    # cv2.imshow('result', res)

    if cv2.waitKey(0):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Without the while loop the sliders appear and everything works. However I need the while loop so I get a live broadcast of my screen and not a still frame. The problem is that if I use the loop the sliders do not appear. How can I fix this?

Thank you!